# Javascript each loop iteration waits for ajax completion

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following code:

```
 $(".subform_book_uploading").each( function(index, subform) {

            var bookId      =   $(subform).find(".form_book").val();
            var filePath    =   $(subform).find(".form_file").val();

            //If values are not empty
            if(bookId != 0 && filePath != 0) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "my Url",
                    data: "my Data",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        Process response

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is that it looks like each iteration waits for ajax completion. In the "Firebug" I see that all ajax requests are executed in series. Is there any way to execute them in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion is, it is actually working in the way it should. It is the debugging process which makes it execute sequentially.

I would suggest using [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) instead of firebug to observe what is happening. When you break on execution, it is quite obvious that you are getting response for the request you have already done so before you hit continue on the breakpoint and next request is issued, you are getting the reply for previous.

Try fiddler and let me know if it is same.

Answer (score 0):

$(".subform_book_uploading").each( function(index, subform) {

```
        var bookId      =   $(subform).find(".form_book").val();
        var filePath    =   $(subform).find(".form_file").val();

        //If values are not empty
        if(bookId != 0 && filePath != 0) {

           setTimeout(function(){ $.ajax({
                url: "my Url",
                data: "my Data",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    Process response

                }
            });},500);
        }
    });
```